# Why can't I follow the conversations of my colleagues despite having a C1 level?

Tags: translation, resources

I know that this question might not be directly related to this group but I am searching an answer

I work where all of the other employees are Italian. Many times it happens that they start talking but I can't get what they are referring to, specially when they narrate what happened to them in some certain event like when they talk to each other in coffee time.

But sometimes when they want me also understand what they are talking, they talk to each other in someway that I can follow.

Exclude dialect, I am only talking about standard Italian.

How do I improve this part of listening and comprehension?

Comment: Maybe also they speak in dialect or using some dialect words not understandable outside the group. For example, we use "menarèl" for the stick to turn the coffee. I think nobody would understand it outside our office.

Comment: @CarLaTeX This is also possible, yes.

Comment: There might be many factors at work. By quoting cases in which "they narrate what happened to them in some certain event" you might refer to conversations that are not focused on professional issues. Should this be the case, always bear in mind that colloquial conversations are fraught with idioms or words that one wouldn't adopt in formal speech. So trying to extend your comprehension to different registers could help.

Comment: Foreigners often notice that  “Italians  talk one way but write  in another way” that is the written language tends to bit more formal and structured than spoken language.

Comment: I guess @Nico is right, there is no dialect, but maybe idioms and informal words. But you say that this happens even in very small offices? with very few people in it? like they speak one way in coffee time and change it during the work?

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti This holds for every language, I reckon. I don't know what your mother tongue is, but I'm pretty sure you do the same.

Comment: Are you able to watch movies in Italian (especially contemporary movies with people talking fast)? If not, subtitled movies are a good exercise to build listening comprehension. What kind of C1 exam did you take? If it is a normal university exam, I should warn you that the level they claim is usually rather inflated (e.g. I'm allegedly a B2 in German, but really I'm not in practice).

Comment: @FabioSpaghetti Yes, it happens, also in families. For example, when I was at the elementary school, in an essay about "What do you do at an ordinary day?", I wrote "Mi sveglio e vado in casa" because we called "casa" the living area of the house, the teacher asked me if I usually sleep in the garden...

Comment: It would be nice and very useful for foreigners to see this colloquial words or expressions in some questions at this site. For instance, questions about their origin or use. I think that Italians are the best ones to be able to do that (as it happens, for instance, at Spanish.SE).

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, I have written this [answer at Meta site](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1429/).

Comment: @CarLaTeX:  This is what's called "lessico famigliare", isn't it? (As that beautiful novel by Natalia Ginzburg).

Comment: @Charo Yes, exactly!

Comment: I have not actually done any test, my assumption is that C1 is my level. but probably as you said, it could be lower

Comment: When we talk casually (in any language), the very structure of understanding is different than when we write or when we speak literately. Apart from the useless advice that you need time to adjust, keep in mind that overhearing other people's conversations shouldn't be mentally "mixed" with other kinds of using language. In your native language, you never know what's been said, you just follow, right? The same's true for a foreign one. Knowing how to find the key word etc, it does not come after you have deciphered all of the message, but rather before. So, think of people, not language...